# Invalid env: "tartan" When using development mode

Tags: plaid

Invalid env: "tartan". env must be "sandbox", "development" or "production"."

The Plaid link will open briefly, then close immediately on android & ios with the following response. I am unsure why this is happening and find no available documentation about this. This was not happening last night without any code modifications, although is happening now for some reason. I have cleaned, rebuilt, redeployed, etc.

This only happens with LinkTokens from Development mode, this does not happen in Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your question was already answered on GitHub, but for posterity — there was an issue on Plaid’s end, and it has since been fixed.